# Localhost refused to connect with my 1st React Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, terminal, localhost, npm-start

I am trying to create my first React Project.
I have opened the Terminal and installed: npx create-react-app
The installation went fine, but when I try to 'npm start' it opens chrome with a local host error where it says localhost refused to connect.

Here is what I see in the terminal:

```
Starting the development server...

/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/React_Project/dojo-blog/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/React_Project/dojo-blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/React_Project/dojo-blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/React_Project/dojo-blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/React_Project/dojo-blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/React_Project/dojo-blog/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/React_Project/dojo-blog/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/React_Project/dojo-blog/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/React_Project/dojo-blog/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.0.1
MacBook-Pro:dojo-blog EgorUlybin$
```

I'm not sure what this means. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532

solved your issue?

Comment: Try 'npm update --save', then run 'npm start' again

Comment: If it doesn't work. Uninstall your nodejs app, download nodejs 16. It is actually recommended for most users

Comment: I installed nodejs v16 and now it works! Thanks a lot!